# Inline Edit (how to render a vuetifiy component based on the condition)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Haii can anyone help me. I'm looping a array I want to render a field based on the condition. which I loop in simple table.my problem is that I'm directly
comparing the index value  (which is index === 0 and secondIndex === 0 ) like that  it seems to be a hardcode. It could be dynamic. I couldn't able to get as a dynamic.Could Anyone help me.

```
 <v-row v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index" no-gutters>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="12" lg="12" xl="12">
            <v-card class="mt-2 rounded-xl" hover>
              <v-card-title v-if="index === 0" @mouseover="mouseOver = true" @mouseleave="mouseOver = false">
              </v-card-title>
              <v-card-subtitle class="pb-5 mt-3">
                <v-row class="ml-1 mt-1 text--primary">
                  <v-icon color="primary">{{item.icon}}</v-icon>
                  <div class="ml-1 text-button">{{item.name}}</div>
                </v-row>
                <v-file-input style="display: none" ref="file" accept="image/*" v-model="systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.logo" @change="uploadProfile()"></v-file-input>
              </v-card-subtitle>
                <v-card-text>
                 <v-form ref="configReference">
                    <div class="ml-9">
                      <tr>
                      <v-simple-table align="justify" style="text-align:justify" v-for="(record, secondIndex) in item.tableValue" :key="secondIndex">
<v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }">
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width:160px">{{record.label}}</th>
                        <td>
                          <p v-if="indexValue === index && secondIndexValue === secondIndex ? showText: true">{{record.value}}</p>
                         <v-col cols="12" md="12" lg="12" xl="12" v-if=" index === 0 && secondIndex === 0  && indexValue === index && secondIndexValue === secondIndex ? show : false">
                            <v-text-field dense hide-details outlined :rules="systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.email ? $_emailValidation : []" :label="$t('email')" v-model="systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.email"></v-text-field>
                          </v-col>
                          <v-col cols="12" lg="12" v-if="index === 0 && secondIndex === 1 && indexValue === index && secondIndexValue === secondIndex ? show : false">
                           <v-autocomplete dense hide-details outlined :label="$t('timezone')" v-model="systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.timezone" :items="listOfTimeZones" item-text="displayname" item-value="standardname"></v-autocomplete>
                          </v-col>
                          </v-col>
                          <v-col cols="12" lg="12" v-if="index === 0 && secondIndex === 2 && indexValue === index && secondIndexValue === secondIndex ? show : false">
                            <v-textarea dense hide-details outlined :label="$t('companyAddress')" v-model="systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.companyaddress"></v-textarea>
                     </v-col></td><td>
                    <v-expand-transition>
                      <v-layout justify-end v-if="hover">
                        <v-fade-transition>
                          <td>
                            <v-btn text x-small icon color="info" v-if="showEdit">
                              <v-icon style="float:right" small  @click="getSingleRecord(index, secondIndex)" color="primary">{{record.icon}}</v-icon>
                            </v-btn>
                          </td>
                        </v-fade-transition>
                      </v-layout>
                    </v-expand-transition>
                   </td>
                </tr>
          </v-row>
    
     list:  [
            {
              name: this.$t('general'),
              icon: 'mdi-folder-multiple-outline',
              tableValue: [
              {
                label: 'Email',
                value: this.systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.email,
                icon: 'mdi-pencil',
                name: 'email'
              },
              {
                label: 'Phone',
                value: this.systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.phone,
                icon: 'mdi-pencil',
                name: 'phone'
              },
              {
                label: 'Company Address',
                value: this.systemAndTenantConfig.systemconfiguration.companyaddress,
                icon: 'mdi-pencil',
                name: 'address'
              }
              ]
         }]
     indexValue: ''
     secondIndexValue: ''

 getSingleRecord (firstIndex, secondIndex) {
      this.indexValue = firstIndex
      this.secondIndexValue = secondIndex
```

}

Comment: Could Anyone help me

Comment: I am afraid it isn't entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. Could you explain what the end goal is? How do you want it to behave? Why should it be dynamic and where is that number supposed to come from?

Comment: I have created inline edit when hover on a  <tr>  edit option will be displayed. I have rendered different fields based on the condition.my problem is that  I have compared   index values  directly 0 1,2 like that Example (index === 0 && secondIndex === 0) this I have used in my code.I want   (index === indexVal && secondIndex === secondIndexVal) Like that dynamic Comparation.